# SeaORM column "owner_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, rust, sea-orm

I have an error with SeaORM, Rust and Postgres, I'm new in the world of the databases so sorry if this is a newbie question. I wanted to refresh the migrations with sea-orm-cli, but i got this error `Execution Error: error returned from database: column "owner_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`.

the full output of the command is this one:

```
Running `cargo run --manifest-path ./migration/Cargo.toml -- fresh -u postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/task_manager`
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.54s
     Running `migration/target/debug/migration fresh -u 'postgres://postgres@localhost:5432/task_manager'`
Dropping table 'seaql_migrations'
Table 'seaql_migrations' has been dropped
Dropping table 'owner'
Table 'owner' has been dropped
Dropping all types
Applying all pending migrations
Applying migration 'm20221106_182043_create_owner_table'
Migration 'm20221106_182043_create_owner_table' has been applied
Applying migration 'm20221106_182552_create_comment_table'
Execution Error: error returned from database: column "owner_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

I thought it could be some problem with my code in the file called `m20221106_182552_create_comment_table.rs`, but I took a look to it and it doesn't seems to be a problem.

```rust
use sea_orm_migration::prelude::*;

use super::m20221106_182043_create_owner_table::Owner;

#[derive(DeriveMigrationName)]
pub struct Migration;

#[async_trait::async_trait]
impl MigrationTrait for Migration {
    async fn up(&self, manager: &SchemaManager) -> Result<(), DbErr> {
        manager
            .create_table(
                Table::create()
                    .table(Comment::Table)
                    .if_not_exists()
                    .col(
                        ColumnDef::new(Comment::Id)
                            .integer()
                            .not_null()
                            .auto_increment()
                            .primary_key(),
                    )
                    .col(ColumnDef::new(Comment::Url).string().not_null())
                    .col(ColumnDef::new(Comment::Body).string().not_null())
                    .col(ColumnDef::new(Comment::IssueUrl).string().not_null())
                    .col(ColumnDef::new(Comment::CreatedAt).string())
                    .col(ColumnDef::new(Comment::UpdatedAt).string())
                    .foreign_key(
                        ForeignKey::create()
                            .name("fk-comment-owner_id")
                            .from(Comment::Table, Comment::OwnerId)
                            .to(Owner::Table, Owner::Id),
                    )
                    .to_owned(),
            )
            .await
    }

    async fn down(&self, manager: &SchemaManager) -> Result<(), DbErr> {
        manager
            .drop_table(Table::drop().table(Comment::Table).to_owned())
            .await
    }
}

#[derive(Iden)]
pub enum Comment {
    Table,
    Id,
    Url,
    Body,
    IssueUrl,
    CreatedAt,
    UpdatedAt,
    OwnerId,
}
```

I was following [this official tutorial](https://www.sea-ql.org/sea-orm-tutorial/ch01-02-migration-cli.html) from the SeaQL team but I don't know if there is something outdated, hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the OwnerId column in the comments table. You have to create it first and then create the FK constraint on it.

See in the tutorial there is

```
                .col(ColumnDef::new(Chef::BakeryId).integer().not_null())
                .foreign_key(
                    ForeignKey::create()
                        .name("fk-chef-bakery_id")
                        .from(Chef::Table, Chef::BakeryId)
                        .to(Bakery::Table, Bakery::Id),
                )
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, my eye had completely missed that line haha